# Haar cascade Trainer using GUI

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I am attempting to use the haar cascade trainer GUI to train a model to detect custom images.

I keep getting the below error whenever my positive images are more than 200. I have 1256 images in my negative(n) folder and 500+ in my positive(p) folder. If I train it with less than or 200 images it will not break but it's not detecting the object accurately when tested.
[image]

Comment: Check which line of training sample is the problem and check its path etc. and maybe remove that line.

Comment: Which of the files should i check this @Micka

Comment: I dont know that gui application. How do you specify the positive samples?

Comment: Can you trll a bit about your chosen parameters? What's your number of stages, the minHitRate, etc.?

Comment: @Micka i am using Haar cascade trainer GUI and for the stages, I did set stages to be 15 stages and the aim here was to detect vehicle plate numbers. The GUI has some default setting that I didn't need to change

Comment: I cant remember the default minHitRate, is it 99.5%? Thst would mean you can lose up to 0.5% of your positive samples per stage and that means you would have to provide about 10% more positive ssmples than specified as training samples

Answer (score 0):

This maybe to late, however just fixed similar issue and found solution somewhere else.
What you need to do when having larger positive images is lower the percentage used with in the Train window. Lowering it to 90% fixed issue.